# IOException: Missing content for multipart request

Tags: java, android, apache-spark, heroku, okhttp

I am trying to send an image via a POST request from an Android app to a Heroku webserver. In the webserver, I want to retrieve the image from the request, modify and then send the modified image back as a response.

However, my current code returns an an IOException in the webserver saying

> java.io.IOException: Missing content for multipart request
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.parse(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:496)org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.getParts(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:405)

I checked and the userImageFile does exist in the Android app at least.

This is my code in the Android app (using OkHttp).

```
    //Creating file with the bitmap gotten from the user
    String path = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    File userImageFile = new File(path + "/image.png");
    userImageFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(userImageFile, false);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fop);
    fop.flush();
    fop.close();

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = "https://my-heroku-app-url-here.com/imageConvert";
    RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("image", userImageFile.getName(),
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), userImageFile))
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();

    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

And this is my code for the Heroku webserver (using the Spark framework).

```
post("/imageConvert", (request, response) -> {
        byte[] body = request.bodyAsBytes();
        request.attribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig", new MultipartConfigElement("/temp"));
        BufferedImage returnImage = null;
        try (InputStream is = request.raw().getPart("image").getInputStream()) {
            BufferedImage userImage = ImageIO.read(is);
            returnImage = getDistortedImage(userImage);
        }catch (IOException ex){
            return "There has been an IO Exception: \n" + ex.getMessage();
        }
        if(returnImage!= null){
            ImageIO.write(returnImage, "png", response.raw().getOutputStream());
            return response.raw();
        }
        return "There was an unknown mistake";
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are consuming the request body twice. If the request contents are consumed once, then you can no longer consume the bytes / stream again just like that, without some explicit resetting mechanism.

You should remove the first statement, so that the second statement is able to consume the input stream.

```
1. byte[] body = request.bodyAsBytes();  // Remove this

2. try (InputStream is = request.raw().getPart("image").getInputStream())
```

Comment: Yup, that works. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad to help!